# Just intonation with Finale Human Playback?

Tags: software, tuning, intonation, orchestral-strings, finale

Is it possible to hear a piece in Finale in just intonation using the "human playback" mode and the built-in Garritan orchestra? If not, what is the best way of doing this, other than live performance? This piece is for a string quartet, arco and pizzicato.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, Finale and its sound libraries do not support anything other than 12-tone equal-temperament at A=440 Hz.

However, you can purchase the full version of the stand-alone [Garritan Personal Orchestra program](http://www.garritan.com/products/personal-orchestra-4/) and use it with Finale in place of the built-in Finale sounds. Garritan Personal Orchestra's ARIA playback engine can be used in any tuning scheme according to the [Scala protocol](http://www.huygens-fokker.org/scala/).

This would not provide you with 100% pure just intonation as it would be played by a live human string quartet; rather, it would enable you to tune 12 notes in an octave to any scheme of mean-tone tuning, such as those used on harpsichords in the Baroque era.

This would be as close as you could get to just intonation using Finale.

Comment: Just to add: The retail version of Finale comes with the GPO sound libraries and offers in total 11 different tunings of equal temperament (from 380-445hz).

Comment: Do you own Finale? What you describe has not been my Finale experience. If you purchased recently, they might have changed things?

Comment: The intonations are part of the aira player. I just tried setting up a piano with Finale's included instruments. The tuning stuff is there; just intonation is available as is a bunch of mean-tone and other tunings.